# ASP.NET Identity User ID to Int error Conversion failed nvarchar Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

My code was working fine but when i tried to make the User ID as Int rather then string by adding in application user and  in all classes.
The add-migration works fine but upon update-database i get the following error.

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value
>   '60b67a91-64e0-4dc7-a85c-abd9521a0b50' to data type int. The statement
>   has been terminated.

Following is the code

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole,
   CustomUserClaim>
{

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(
UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(
            this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRole() { }
    public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int,
    CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ClinicContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRoleStore(ClinicContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
{
    public CustomUserManager(CustomUserStore store) : base(store) { }

}
public class CustomRoleManager : RoleManager<CustomRole, int>
{
    public CustomRoleManager(CustomRoleStore store) : base(store) { }
}
```

My DB context as :

```
public partial class ClinicContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole,
    int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public ClinicContext()
            : base("name=ClinicContext")
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: You've got existing rows with `nvarchar` IDs and your update script doesn't know how to convert the GUID into an `int`. If you don't really need this data it would probably be easiest to drop the rows especially if you've configured the database to generate Id.

Comment: Thank you please post this as answer so i will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got existing rows with `nvarchar` IDs and your update script doesn't know how to convert the GUID into an `int`.

If you don't really need this data it would probably be easiest to drop the rows -- Especially if you've configured the database to generate Id.